# Angular Js custom directive for master data drop down

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

New to Angular JS,

I trying to define custom directive for dropdown with data from web service.

Now trying to do with some static data but not working.

```
app.directive("deviceBranch", function(){
    return {
        templateUrl : 'resources/view/template/device-branch-list.html',
        controller : function($scope) {
            $scope.listBranch = [{
                deviceBranchId:"id1",
                deviceBranchName:"value1"
            },{
                deviceBranchId:"id2",
                deviceBranchName:"value2"
            },{
                deviceBranchId:"id3",
                deviceBranchName:"valkue3"
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Added "Select" in the template with-

```
ng-options="service.deviceBranchId as service.deviceBranchName for service in listBranch"
```

This is how I am using directive

```
<device-branch></device-branch>
```

Select is populated, but no options are available.

Please assist.

Comment: I would like to populate options from webservice

Comment: can you post your template ? or even better a plker reproducing your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were just missing an ng-model in your template. Below is a link to a working sample.

```
<select ng-options="service.deviceBranchId as service.deviceBranchName for service in listBranch" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

You can also inject $http into your directive to get data from web services.

```
app.directive("deviceBranch", function($http){
  return {
    templateUrl : 'device-branch-list.html',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    controller : function($scope) {
        $scope.listBranch = [{
            deviceBranchId:"id1",
            deviceBranchName:"value1"
        },{
            deviceBranchId:"id2",
            deviceBranchName:"value2"
        },{
            deviceBranchId:"id3",
            deviceBranchName:"valkue3"
        }]
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs){
      //var url = ""
      //$http.get(url).then(function(response){
      // $scope.listBranch = response;
      //})
    }
  }
});
```

Here's the template (device-branch-list.html):

```
<select ng-options="service.deviceBranchId as service.deviceBranchName for service in listBranch" ng-model="ngModel">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/essg24GsrhSKwqXO578p?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like to give custom model name, because this directive can be use more than once on same page. 
Please try to give update

Comment: I've updated the plnkr so that you could add ng-model onto the directive. The variable you pass will now two way bind with the input as seen in the demo. The changes includes adding 'ng-model' to script.js and index.html. Also a change on the template html file to change from 'selected' to 'ngModel'